# Make Chrome browser prefer DNS over searching

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Teach Google Chrome to understand custom TLD](https://superuser.com/questions/274562/teach-google-chrome-to-understand-custom-tld)

Is it possible to let the Chrome browser prefer all DNS resolvable URLs over a search? 
Everytime I use a local name not matching a usual domain scheme, I got search results for it.

I first thought that no nonsense DNS lookup is made if the URL seems to be a search keyword, however Chrome always detect this condition and asks me if I like to go to my domain instead. So the DNS lookup is made anyway.

Comment: Is it the same question? http://superuser.com/questions/274562/teach-google-chrome-to-understand-custom-tld

Answer (score 3):

frustrating feature, isn't it?  Adding a trailing slash to the name will prevent the search

"myserver/" wil go directly to http://myserver