# PC version of Google Chrome doesn't recognize ".local" domain name

Tags: google-chrome, zeroconf, mdns

With Bonjour installed in PC, I can access my server in Mac with ".local". For example, I can access my mac with the name "prosseek.local".

The problem is that in Chrome for PC, it doesn't recognize "local" to open search page instead of accessing mac server.

This issue isn't happening with other web browsers (explore/firefox) in PC. What is even wierder is that chrome seems to recognize the ".local" sometimes, but not always.

How to solve this issue? Or, how can I teach chrome that ".local" is a part of page name in order not to direct to search page?

### ADDED

It seems that this problem has been a while, so I think google is not that interested in solving this issue which is a show stopper to prevent using chrome.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30636

I found other web pages, but not so useful in solving this issue

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877705/chrome-browser-doesnt-like-a-domain-with-loc-tld-for-localhost-domain-testing
- [Teach Google Chrome to understand custom TLD](https://superuser.com/questions/274562/teach-google-chrome-to-understand-custom-tld)

Comment: Have you tried to prefix `prosseek.local` with `http://`, so it becomes `http://prosseek.local`?

Comment: @criziot: Yes, I did, the thing is that chrome seems to automatically remove http://  even though I prepend it.

Comment: @prosseek, nowadays browsers remove the URL prefix to "save" space on the address bar, applying it to the location security notice visible before the address bar, if the website uses a certificate of some kind! It is not removed, just not presented.

Comment: @prosseek: Have you checked to ensure that Windows itself can reliably resolve the host name. Such as pinging it in cmd.exe? It might not be a Chrome problem.

Comment: Instead of prepending `https://`, *append* a `/`: `prosseek.local/`. If that doesn’t work, then Chrome just doesn’t support `.local` URLs. Check if you are using the latest version, and if so, then just give it time (or file a [bug-report/feature-request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) since it does not seem to have come up already).

Comment: @David C. Bishop: It works fine with cmd.exe, and it also works fine with other web browsers.

Comment: How about adding the relevant IP address for `prosseek.local` to your Windows `hosts` file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`)?  Not terribly scalable, but it could serve the needs of development work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add it to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts (be sure to open as Administrator so you have access to write to that file)

```
127.0.0.1 prosseek.local
```

then run

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

and you should be able to

```
ping prosseek.local
```

Note: if chrome still ignores the hostname just add a trailing forward slash, e.g. prosseek.local/ which will bypass the search. Source: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30636

Comment: This might solve a small problem, but does not solve the real problem. If people want to point to own host just type localhost. Microsoft uses .local domains on small company networks and people can't just edit all hosts computer files to add all the subdomains they add..

Comment: According to the question, proseek.local is the user's mac, and chrome is having this problem on Windows. Therefore 127.0.0.1 is not the right IP address. .local is a special domain that means use mDNS to resolve the IP address. It is not something you set up on a DNS or DHCP server, it works using multicast messages to ask all the computers on the LAN.

Comment: Thanks for the idea to add a trailing forward slash!

Answer (score 10):

Call your .local domain **once** in Chrome prepending it with the `http://` or `https://` scheme (e.g.: http://mywebsite.local ).
This will avoid the Google search and instead will call your local website.

You only need to do this once. From this moment on you can enter the local URL **without** `http://` or `https://` and it will still be loaded locally (e.g.: mywebsite.local ).

Comment: This did the trick.

Comment: This is lame to have to do for every host on my local network from every instance of Chrome on every machine.  Chrome devs, if you're watching, give us a mechanism that s*cks less, please.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to just add a `/` at the end. For example, type `mywebsite.local/` in the address bar and hit Enter. You don't even need to write `http://` or `https://` at the beginning.